# will I miss any content or options by buying dark souls 2 scholar instead of the base version?

Tags: dark-souls-2, dark-souls-2-sotfs

I haven't played any Dark Souls 2 at all. And the difficulty of Dark Souls 1, while interesting was a bit much. I heard Dark Souls 2 Scholar raises the difficulty of DS2. So I was thinking I should buy the base DS2 game without scholar. Unless there are options in DS2:Scholar that let you play easier version and you don't miss any content.

Is there content not in DS2:Scholar that is in DS2 base? Can I play the original difficulty buying DS2:Scholar?

Answer (score 1):

Basically DS2 SotFS includes all content of DS2 and 3 DLC.

But it also changes some minor things, for example casual enemy placements. In majority of cases it makes the game a bit more difficult, but also more meaningful (i.e. you have to think more and press R1 less).

Concluding:

1. If you care only about major content (like bosses or areas) there is no difference. (But if you happened to not get the latest version of DS2, but one of the first versions, you'll miss not only DLC, but also one optional boss).
2. If you care about quality of content SotFS is better.
3. If you care about difficulty DS2 is simplier than SotFS.

P.S. Also if you care about PvP, it is of course more active in the latest version, i.e. SotFS.
P.P.S. This can be subjective, but DS2 difficulty is smaller than DS1, basically only DLCs are quite difficult.

Comment: what does R1 do?

Comment: @Maslow, weapon attack, the quickest one.

Comment: "If you care about quality of content Scholar is better.", that's an opinion, consider removing.